# How to open new activity without effecting bottom nevigation

Tags: android, xml, bottomnavigationview

I have three activities all connected to bottom navigation, but one(activity_calculator) has buttons that open new activities[xml of activity_calculator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pjRe.png), how can i open new activities[this is the initial plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwoo6.png) without changing the bottom navigation and if pressed should have me back to activity_calculator
[this is now main_activity looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8259.png)
ands this is the MainActivity.java [how bottom navagation is implemented](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhCUX.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make Bottom Navigation as a parent activity with framelayout in xml. then call each child activities in the frame layout using tabhost. Extend parent activity with TabActivity